# How to find the variance of a variable defined by a random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, variance

I need help with this problem:

> If $X$ is a uniform random variable over $(0,1)$, define another variable $Y$ by:
>   $Y =\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
>              \\ 1 &  , & X\leq0.5 \\
>              \\ 2 &  ,  & X >0.5
> \end{array}\right.$
>
> Find the variance of Y.

Ok, I know that $Var(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2$, so I tried to find the expected value first. So I tried to find it like this:
$$E(Y)=\int_0^{0.5} 1\cdot1dx+\int_0^{0.5} 2\cdot1dx=0.5+2(0.5)=1.5$$
I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct, hope you can help me.

Comment: Looks good so far!  Can you work out $E[Y^2]$ the same way?

Comment: Great! I guess that I woudl have to square the values of $Y$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elementary way to handle this exercise would be using the theorem
$$
E[g(X)]=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty }g(t)f_X(t)\,\mathrm d t\tag1
$$
named as [the law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) (in this case stated for a continuous random variable $X$). Then we need to find some function $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $g(X)=Y$.

Then setting:
$$
g(t):=\begin{cases}
1,&t\leqslant 1/2\\
2,&t>1/2
\end{cases}\tag2
$$
we find that $g(X)=Y$ so we can apply $\rm(1)$ knowing that in this case $f_X:=\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}$, where $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ is [the indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $A$.

Hence
$$
\begin{align*}
E[Y]=E[g(X)]=\int_{0}^1g(t)\,\mathrm d t=\frac1{2}+2\cdot \frac1{2}=\frac{3}{2}\tag3\\
E[Y^2]=E[g(X)^2]=\int_{0}^1(g(t))^2\,\mathrm d t=\frac1{2}+4\cdot \frac1{2}=\frac{5}{2}\tag4
\end{align*}
$$
where we deduced that $\operatorname{Var}[Y]=\frac1{4}$.

---

Another way to handle this exercise is using directly measure theoretic definitions and concepts, in this case we will have that
$$
\begin{align*}
E[Y]:&=\int_\Omega Y(\omega )dP(\omega )\\
&=\int_{X^{-1}(-\infty ,1/2]}dP(\omega )+\int_{X^{-1}(1/2,\infty )}2 dP(\omega )\\
&=\int_{(-\infty,1/2]}f_X(t)\,\mathrm d t+2\int_{(1/2,\infty )}f_X(t)\,\mathrm d t\\
&=\int_{(0,1/2]}\,\mathrm d t+2\int_{(1/2,1)}\,\mathrm d t\\
&=\frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}
$$
because $X$ have as density $f_X:=\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}$. And similarly
$$
\begin{align*}
E[Y^2]&=\int_{\Omega }Y^2(\omega )dP(\omega )\\
&=\int_{X^{-1}(-\infty ,1/2]}dP(\omega )+\int_{X^{-1}(1/2,\infty )}2^2dP(\omega )\\
&=\int_{(-\infty ,1/2]}f_X(t)\,\mathrm d t+4\int_{(1/2,\infty )}f_X(t)\,\mathrm d t\\
&=\int_{(0,1/2)}\,\mathrm d t+4\int_{(1/2,1)}\,\mathrm d t\\
&=\frac{5}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Whatt is $dP(\omega)$? Also why is the region we of integration$X^{-1}(-\infty,1/2)? I am confused with the $-1$ power.

Comment: $dP$ is the probability measure and $X^{-1}(-\infty ,1/2]$ is the subset of $\Omega$ where $X(\omega )\leqslant 1/2$ holds. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_case)

Comment: And why is $X$ to the power of $-1$? Is there somewhere I can read a bit more about this? I'm sure we haven't seen this at class.

Comment: @david sorry if what I had written is so advanced for your context. It is probability theory in the language of measure theory, maybe this answer is not appropriated for you. However by now I dont know exactly how to solve your exercise using other methods. If you are curious you can learn probability theory in this way by example from [these notes](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~web6720/MATH%206710%20notes.pdf) or something else (search in google by "probability theory notes" or something like that)

Comment: I see, I'm currently taking Introduction to probability and I was told that a similar problem was going to be on the final exam. Thank you for the notes, I'll read them.

Comment: @david I have rewritten my answer from a more elementary point of view. To learn measure theory you will need at least 1-2 months, it is not an easy task. Anyway if you are interested it will be better to study both things (probability theory and measure theory) from some textbook, what explain everything carefully and slowly (the notes of my previous comment doesn't seem adequate for this)

Comment: @Masacroso ¿qué sombrero tienes? (What kind of hat do you have?)

Answer (score 0):

$P\{\omega: Y(\omega) = 1\} = P\{\omega: X(\omega) \le 0.5\} = {1\over 2}$, likewise $P\{\omega: Y(\omega) = 2\} = {1\over 2}$. So $E(Y) = {1\over 2} \times 1 + {1\over 2}\times 2 = 1.5$, and 
$$
Var(Y) = \sum P\{Y = x\}\times (x - E(Y))^2 \\ = {1\over 2} \times 0.5^2 \times 2 = 0.25
$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more and explain the notation? I'm not familiar with it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Phrasing things as you might see them in an Introductory Probability Theory class:

Note that the probability density function of $X$, $f_X(x)$, equals 1 over its support, $[0,1]$. Then:

$$E(Y) = \int_0^1 y(x)*f_X(x) dx = \int_0^{.5} y(x)*f_X(x) dx + \int_{.5}^1 y(x)*f_X(x) dx 
\\= \int_0^{.5} 1*1 dx + \int_{.5}^1 2*1 dx = \frac{1}{2} + 1 = \frac{3}{2}$$

$$E(Y^2) = \int_0^1 y(x)^2*f_X(x) dx = \int_0^{.5} y(x)^2*f_X(x) dx + \int_{.5}^1 y(x)^2*f_X(x) dx 
\\ = \int_0^{.5} 1^2*1dx + \int_{.5}^1 2^2*1dx = \frac{1}{2} + 2 = \frac{5}{2}$$

then $V(Y) = E(Y^2) - (E(Y))^2 = \frac{5}{2} - {(\frac{3}{2})}^2 = \frac{1}{4}$

Anytime you have a function of a random variable: $Z = g(X)$, $Z$ is also a random variable. If we let $f_X(x)$ denote the probability density function of $X$, $E(Z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)*f_X(x) dx$.